# Best Practice For Structuring My Type

Tags: c#, parsing, logging

I have logs I am attempting to code a utility to parse.

These logs are structured as CSVs, but the amount of sections (columns) varies depending on the "Transaction Type". There are approximately 50 different possibilities of "Transaction Type" so making a class for each is not feasible.

Example Log Entries:

```
2016-08-02 10:36:30.578 (Machine: 00124) Received: 1120228,T,2016-08-02 10:36:30,5,18441,209719,1,20
2016-08-02 10:36:30.594 (Machine: 00124) Sent: 1120228,T,2016-08-02 10:36:30,0,,0,18441,DhfMAAfjhsb6CiW55999999TbNakCC3Fc8jaZ
```

Every `Received` has a matching `Sent`. The values, and represented parameters differ by `Received` and `Sent` as well as Transaction Type.

The idea, and current implementation is as follow.

1. Load line and split on COMMA (,)
2. Determine "Transaction Type"
3. Load associated schema from an XML and gain the parameter the value represents for each.
4. Store in a type depending on if it's `Received` or `Sent`

Current Implementation:

```
public class Message : IMessage
        {
            private List<Received> _receivedMessage;
            private List<Sent> _sentMessage;

            public Message()
            {
                ReceivedMessage = new List<Received>();
                SentMessage = new List<Sent>();
            }

            public Message(
                    string messageID,
                    List<Received> receivedMessage,
                    List<Sent> sentMessage,
                    string storedProcedure,
                    string transShortName)
            {
                MessageID = messageID;
                ReceivedMessage = receivedMessage;
                SentMessage = sentMessage;
                StoredProcedure = storedProcedure;
                TransShortName = transShortName;
            }

            public string MessageID { get; set; }

            public List<Received> ReceivedMessage
            {
                get { return new List<Received>(_receivedMessage.OrderBy(_ => _.Position)); }
                set { _receivedMessage = value; }
            }

            public List<Sent> SentMessage
            {
                get { return new List<Sent>(_sentMessage.OrderBy(_ => _.Position)); }
                set { _sentMessage = value; }
            }

            public string StoredProcedure { get; set; }

            public string TransShortName { get; set; }

            public class Sent : ISent
            {
                public string MessageID { get; set; }

                public dynamic Value { get; set; }

                public string Parameter { get; set; }

                public string Position { get; set; }
            }

            public class Received : IReceived
            {
                public string MessageID { get; set; }

                public dynamic Value { get; set; }

                public string Error { get; set; }

                public string Parameter { get; set; }

                public string Position { get; set; }

                public string Regex { get; set; }

                //public string TransShortName { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

ISent Interface:

```
public interface ISent
    {
        string Parameter { get; set; }
        string Position { get; set; }
        dynamic Value { get; set; }
    }
```

IReceived Interface:

```
 public interface  IReceived
    {
        string Error { get; set; }
        string Parameter { get; set; }
        string Position { get; set; }
        string Regex { get; set; }
        //string TransShortName { get; set; }
    }
```

Idea, best practices, anything, are graciously welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have a class for each type, then I'd suggest having the common properties as regular properties and the dynamic properties as Key/Value pairs in a dictionary. At some point in your code, you're going to have to know what properties are in a type though.

Also, if you have a schema for all 50 types, you can generate the C# classes from the schema using the XSD command line tool. The naming conventions might be a little wacky though :).

Comment: I do know what's in them by referencing the parsed XML transaction schema and looking up by Transaction Type. I basically have something similar in my current setup. Each line becomes a `List<Received>` or `List<Sent>` respectively.

Comment: @DevinStokes and I would ask this question, do you really need these two types ISent and IReceived ? You could have an enum as a property to specify the type to complete the SledgeHammer's answer (in the sense one class only to manage the whole).

Comment: I imagine that would work. So what you're saying is implement say "ITransactionMessage" with `Parameter` `Position` and `Value`?